# How can I push Django code using dj-database-url, psycopg2 to Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

I am currently building a web project in Django and working on getting the site ready for deployment. I initially deployed the site on Heroku using Sqlite3, with my database code in settings as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

However, due to Heroku's ephemeral file system I realized I needed to switch to Postgres. After following a few different guides I arrived at the following changes to my settings. I first deleted the "DATABASES" as mentioned above and replaced it with the following:

```
import dj_database_url, psycopg2

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': *************,                      
        'USER': **************,
        'PASSWORD': ************************************,
        'HOST': *********************,
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

When I make these changes everything works perfectly on the local Django development server (127.0.0.1:8000), but once I push the changes through Git and to Heroku I try opening my site on Heroku and get "Application Error" and a suggestion to check my logs. Which report "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named dj_database_url" and similarly any outside library I try to upload to Heroku appears to have this issue. How can I fix this issue and move my site into production? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[You need to include them in your `requirements.txt` file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#expected-files-for-python) or however the buildpack you're using expects the applications dependencies to be indicated.

Comment: They are in my requirements.txt file as you can see. Note I deleted some lines in the requirements file to have enough room for comment, but theyre all there. Yet still have the error
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
django-heroku==0.3.1
pandas==0.25.1
pathspec==0.5.9
pipenv==2018.11.26
psycopg2==2.8.4
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
pylint==2.3.1
pylint-django==2.0.11
pylint-plugin-utils==0.5
pypiwin32==223
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-dotenv==0.10.3
pytz==2019.2
pywin32==226
soupsieve==1.9.3
sqlparse==0.3.0
virtualenv==16.7.4
virtualenv-clone==0.5.3

Comment: Is your requirements file included in your repository? Does it get pushed to heroku? You can verify the latter with opening a bash shell with`heroku run bash` and then run `ls` in the shell to see what files exist.

Comment: It says that requirements.txt is in my repository. I think it may have something to do with the environment in which they were installed...i dont think those were added in a virtual environment, but pipenv and the libraries are in my Desktop/lib/site-packages folder which is distinct from the the location I've been doing my project in (which is called Desktop/news). I am not sure how to get the virtual environment "back up" and/or get dj_database_url and psycopg2 from lib/sitepackages to where I need to be - either Desktop or in my projects top-level directory??